# array of structures - sizeof returning unexpected result

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have an array of simple structures declared in my code. A 
 `sizeof()` response is being returned that does not match the size of the array. Is there some other way that this should be declared to ensure the correct sizeof response?

```
struct control_cmd {
    const char * cmd;
    void (*cmd_fn)(int,char *(*)[],char*);
};

struct control_cmd control_cmds[]={
    {"ANNOUNCE",control_announce},
    {"SEND",control_send}
};
```

`sizeof(control_cmds)` returns a value of `16` when I am expecting a value of `2`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is the size in memory, not the number of elements. In case of an array (not a pointer!) you can obtain the number of elements by dividing the size of the array by the size of a single element, i.e., `sizeof(control_cmds) / sizeof(*control_cmds)`.

Comment: That is, on your machine each `struct control_cmd` is 8 bytes (= 2 × 32 bits for the two pointers it contains). You have two of them in the array `control_cmds`, so its size is 2 × 8 = 16 bytes. Since it is an array and not just a pointer to its first element, you can use `sizeof(control_cmds)` to find out its total size, here 16, but for the count you need to divide it by `sizeof(struct control_cmd)`, which can be expressed by `sizeof(*control_cmds)` as `*control_cmds` is the first element (which is not actually accessed here, but only used a convenient way to get the size of its type).

Answer (score 1):

I would typedef `control_cmd_t`, declare `control_cmds` as an array of `control_cmd_t`, and divide the two. (Very similar to Arkku's answer).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct control_cmd_t__ {
    const char * cmd;
    void (*cmd_fn)(int,char *(*)[],char*);
} control_cmd_t;

control_cmd_t control_cmds[]={
    {"ANNOUNCE",control_announce},
    {"SEND",control_send}
};

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof control_cmd_t is: %ld\n", sizeof(control_cmd_t));
    printf("sizeof control_cmds is: %ld\n", sizeof(control_cmds));
    printf("number of elements in control_cmds is: %d", (sizeof(control_cmds)/sizeof(control_cmd_t)));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof control_cmd_t is: 16
sizeof control_cmds is: 32
number of elements in control_cmds is: 2
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking for the size of the array, not the size of a single element in the array, it's just coincidence that their expected result (2) is also the number of things in the element (`struct control_cmd`).

Comment: Correct. I am not interested in the size of control_cmd_t - I want to know how many elements there are in the array.

Comment: Thanks @Arkku and Mark.  I misunderstood the OPs question. I've edited my answer accordingly.